# Convert the any locale Date to en-US locale date string

Tags: angular, date, momentjs, locale

I have converted the application to German as regional Format and the locale_id is registered as I am able to see the expected date format. But as I have date shown in German Format which is 13.10.2020 (*it uses "." special character and format is "DD.MM.YYYY"*)

When I select the date from date picker it gets selected as expected but while saving i have to convert the format in normal en-US locale for the data base to store.

For example -
German as locale_ID -> Date format is DD.MM.YYYY
But while saving I want to convert it in YYYY-MM-DD

I have tried following -

1. FormatDate("DD.MM.YYYY", "shortDate", "en-US") of @angular/common but it throws an Invalid Date error
2. moment("DD.MM.YYYY").format("YYYY-MM-DD") of moment.js but this gives me Invalid Date.

Could you help me that how exactly should i change the date to en-US locale without changing the locale_Id as I want the system in German only.

My system accepts almost all the locales so German to en-US is one of an example. So I am looking for some generic way to convert it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this with Moment.js

```
console.log(moment("02.04.2021", "DD.MM.YYYY").format('YYYY-MM-DD'));

    moment.locale(this.locale);
    if (!format) { format = "YYYY-MM-DD"; }
    var localeFormat = moment.localeData().longDateFormat('L');
    return moment(date, localeFormat).format(format);
```

Comment: Yeah, but this will only convert the German format. This will not help when I have some different locale. Hence I  have done                                                                                 
   `this. moment.locale(this.locale);
    if (!format) { format = "YYYY-MM-DD"; }
    var localeFormat = moment.localeData().longDateFormat('L');
    return moment(date, localeFormat).format(format);`

Comment: This doesn't work for zh-hant locale. It gives invalid. :( So please go https://momentjs.com/ and check if your locales is supported or not in Multiple Locale Support section.